# Kafka source connect poll method called by multiple threads

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have written a file source connect, I tried starting it in standalone and as well as distributed mode.. I notice sometimes the poll method is called by multiple threads. I understand if we create a task - that will be assigned to a worker which assigns a single thread and poll method is called by only this thread. But in my case it is behaving differently.
Can somebody please explain me under what circumstances a source task is executed by multiple threads concurrently. This is creating issue for my implementation

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be some issue with version. Upgraded now to confluent 3.2.2 and kafka and Kafka 0.10.2.1-cp2. Working without any issues.. we are moving ahead with this excellent platform.